# Music Notation Software with API

Tags: music, music-composing, music-sheet

I am looking for a music notation software which offers an API to code additional music.
For example Id like to write a melody in the GUI and code an algorithm which dynamically plays along with the melody.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer the GUI part in your question, I would recommend [MuseScore](https://musescore.org). It is Open Source and has a Plugin System, so you may extend it to your needs. MuseScore is based on Qt.

However, if you are looking for an even more programmable approach, you should check [LilyPond](http://lilypond.org). This is kind of LaTeX for music notation.